# How to Submit Form Data

Tags: python, html, django

I want to submit form data to an email template and then send said email. However, no data is being returned in the response. I believe this is an easy problem, but I am inexperienced with Python/Django. I think there is some minor detail I have wrong which is causing issues. Any input is very much appreciated!

Views.py

```
def new_opportunity_submit(request):
    form_class = OpportunityForm

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            account_manager = request.POST.get('account_manager')
            inside_solutions = request.POST.get('inside_solutions')
            selected_company = request.POST.get('selected_company')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('new_opportunity_submit.txt')

            context = {
                'account_manager': account_manager,
                'inside_solutions': inside_solutions,
                'selected_company': selected_company
            }
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form submission",
                content,
                "Your website" + '',
                ['youremail@gmail.com'],
                headers={'Reply-To': ''}
            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('opportunities')

            return render(request, 'website/opportunities.html', {'form': form_class})
```

Opportunities.html

```
<form action="{% url 'new_opportunity_submit' %}" method="post" id="newOpportunityForm" data-location-url="{% url 'new_opportunity_location' %}"
          data-contact-url="{% url 'new_opportunity_contact' %}" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Account Manager:</label>
            <div class="select">
                <select name="account_manager" id="account_manager">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="">Person 1</option>
                    <option value="">Person 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Inside Solutions:</label>
            <div class="select">
                <select name="inside_solutions" id="inside_solutions">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="">Person 1</option>
                    <option value="">Person 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Client Information:</label>
            <div class="select">
                <select name="selectcompanies" id="selectcompanies">
                    <option value="">Company</option>
                    {% for company in companies %}
                    <option value="" name="selected_company" id="selected_company">{{ company.name }}</option>}
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Opportunity, ClientInformation, OpportunityName, DealRegistration


class OpportunityForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Opportunity
        fields = ('account_manager', 'inside_solutions', 'selected_company')
```

Models.py

```
class CloseDate(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()


class DealRegistration(models.Model):
    deal = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deal


class OpportunityName(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    practice = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company


class ClientInformation(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company


class Opportunity(models.Model):
    accountManger = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    insideSolutions = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    clientInformation = models.ForeignKey(ClientInformation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    opportunityName = models.ForeignKey(OpportunityName, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    dealRegistration = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    closeDate = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.opportunityName
```

Company.Object

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "identifier": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "status": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "addressLine1": "string",
    "addressLine2": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "state": "string",
    "zip": "string",
    "country": {
      "id": 0,
      "identifier": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "phoneNumber": "string",
    "faxNumber": "string",
    "website": "string",
    "territory": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "market": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "accountNumber": "string",
    "defaultContact": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "dateAcquired": "2019-06-10T16:08:25Z",
    "sicCode": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "parentCompany": {
      "id": 0,
      "identifier": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "annualRevenue": 0,
    "numberOfEmployees": 0,
    "ownershipType": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "timeZoneSetup": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "leadSource": "string",
    "leadFlag": true,
    "unsubscribeFlag": true,
    "calendar": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "userDefinedField1": "string",
    "userDefinedField2": "string",
    "userDefinedField3": "string",
    "userDefinedField4": "string",
    "userDefinedField5": "string",
    "userDefinedField6": "string",
    "userDefinedField7": "string",
    "userDefinedField8": "string",
    "userDefinedField9": "string",
    "userDefinedField10": "string",
    "vendorIdentifier": "string",
    "taxIdentifier": "string",
    "taxCode": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "billingTerms": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "invoiceTemplate": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "pricingSchedule": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "companyEntityType": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "billToCompany": {
      "id": 0,
      "identifier": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "billingSite": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "billingContact": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "invoiceDeliveryMethod": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "invoiceToEmailAddress": "string",
    "invoiceCCEmailAddress": "string",
    "deletedFlag": true,
    "dateDeleted": "2019-06-10T16:08:25Z",
    "deletedBy": "string",
    "mobileGuid": {},
    "facebookUrl": "string",
    "twitterUrl": "string",
    "linkedInUrl": "string",
    "currency": {
      "id": 0,
      "symbol": "string",
      "isoCode": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "territoryManager": {
      "id": 0,
      "identifier": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "_info": {}
    },
    "typeIds": [
      0
    ],
    "_info": {},
    "customFields": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "caption": "string",
        "type": "Button",
        "entryMethod": "EntryField",
        "numberOfDecimals": 0,
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Dependent Drop-Down Script

```
<script>
    $("#selectcompanies").change(function () {
        var location_url = $("#newOpportunityForm").attr("data-location-url");  
        var contact_url = $("#newOpportunityForm").attr("data-contact-url");
        var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected"); 
        var company   = optionSelected.text();

        $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
            url: location_url,                    
                data: {
                'selected_company': company       
                    },
            success: function (data) {   
                console.log(data)
                $("#selectlocations").html(data);  
                $("#auto_company").html(company);
                }
        });

        $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
            url: contact_url,                    
                data: {
                'selected_company': company       
                    },
            success: function (data) {   
                console.log(data)
                $("#selectcontacts").html(data);  
                }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: `<option value="">Person 1</option>` Even though "Person 1" is displayed on the form, the actual value submitted is `value=""`, i.e. it's blank.  This probably leads to the form validation failing, which you don't appear to be handling.

Comment: There are 2 returns in the same indentation.

Comment: @DaniloAkamine Yeah, I noticed that.  Perhaps the second return is actually meant to be outdented one level?

Comment: @JohnGordon I guess so, but the question is a little bit vague for me. We need more clarification.

Comment: Like @JohnGordon said, your dropdowns do not have a value parameter attached to the DOM elements. If you fill them in, that should work.

Comment: @JohnGordon How would I set the value to the option selected from the JSON response? So, value={{ company.name }}

Comment: That input item selects an account manager, so it seems like the value should be a person ID.  But you haven't shown us that model, nor how it's used, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @JohnGordon for the "Client Information" div, the user selects an option from the drop-down list which is populated via JSON response. I want to use the selected option as the option value of that same drop-down for form submission. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense.  But you asked specifically what should go in the value attribute, and I can't tell you, because your question does not contain enough detail.

Comment: @JohnGordon I see, what information do you need? The options for selected_comapny are particular company names which are dynamically populated whereas options for account_manager are hard-coded. I have the value set for account_manager fine now, just selected_company I am having some trouble with.

Comment: Your template expects to see an item named `companies` which is a list of companies to display in the form.  So, your view function needs to pass that list to the template render call.  Please show us the view function that displays the initial form.  (You showed us the view that handles the form *submission*, but not the form *display*.)

Comment: @JohnGordon `def opportunities(request):
    companies = cwObj.get_companies()
    context = {'companies': companies}
    return render(request, 'website/opportunities.html', context)`

Comment: Probably you want something like `value="{{company.id}}"`, but again, you haven't shown us the company object definition, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have tried {{company.id}} but it still returns 'None'. I added the object definition in the original post.

Comment: According to that data layout, `company.id` should work.  Is the form displaying `company.name` correctly?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, `company.name` populates the drop-down properly as well as all other attributes. When I try to hard-code the option value to some string, the value returns 'None' still.

Comment: Then it looks like `cwObj.get_companies()` is not returning the correct data.  Can you run that function in a python shell and look at the output?

Comment: @JohnGordon see my edit on my last comment. I have check the data returned by `get_companies` and everything is returned correctly. This drop-down is the first of a dependent drop-down chain, maybe my script used to handle this functionality is creating the issue? I added the script in the original post.

Comment: If `get_companies()` is returning objects that correctly have `company.name` and `company.id` set, and your form template is using `value={{company.id}}` for the selected company dropdown, then I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm very sorry, I used the reference of `selected_company` and not `selectcompanies`. It is working now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the `<option>` DOM elements a `value`. Right now they're blank. Try something like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'new_opportunity_submit' %}" method="post" id="newOpportunityForm" data-location-url="{% url 'new_opportunity_location' %}"
          data-contact-url="{% url 'new_opportunity_contact' %}" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Account Manager:</label>
            <div class="select">
                <select name="account_manager" id="account_manager">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="person_1">Person 1</option>
                    <option value="person_2">Person 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also, in your `views.py`, once you populate the form using `form = form_class(request.POST)`, you can do:
`account_manager = form_class.cleaned_data['account_manager']`

If you are using fields in your form that are same as the fields on the model, you might want to consider using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). They're much more cleaner and easier to maintain. If you used a model form, you could just do this in your views:

```
form = OpportunityForm(request.POST)
form.save()
```

Comment: When I use cleaned_data['vaue'] I receive a KeyError for the value.